# FOR /F returning blank result

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I've wrote a little code to return the lines of a text file one by one. It works, but at the end, it returns a blank result.

How can I get rid of that blank result?

So far, the code is as follows:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (test.txt) do call :maq %%a

:maq
Echo %*
```

Comment: Maybe your file has an extra `NL` character at the end?

Comment: The file has 2 lines: 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put an `goto :eof` between `:maq` and your `for`, that is:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (test.txt) do call :maq %%a
goto :eof
:maq Echo %*
```

otherwise there's an echo echoing something, in this case nothing 'cause your program maybe didn't received any parameters.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!! What does :eof stands for?

Comment: `goto :eof` breaks the context the execution is in.

Comment: `goto :eof` is equivalent to `exit /B`. I personally prefer `exit /B` to end a subroutine and `goto :eof` to end the main file...

Answer (score 0):

You are falling through the code and executing the last line one more time after iterating through the do loop.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (test.txt) do echo %%a
```

is all you need. If you must use a subroutine then do something like this:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (test.txt) do call :maq %%a
goto :eof

:maq
Echo %*
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I intend to use this with a subroutine so I used the second suggestion. :) What does :eof stands for?

Comment: end of file. the first one is so that you don't fall into the subroutine and the second one is to return from the subroutine.